# Adding CSS to custom post type admin page causes error

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, admin, css

I have this bit of code in my [Meteor Slides](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/meteor-slides/) plugin that loads a stylesheet on the admin pages of just the slides custom post type:

```
    add_action('admin_head', 'meteorslides_admin_css');

function meteorslides_admin_css() {

    global $post_type;

    if (($_GET['post_type'] == 'slide') || ($post_type == 'slide')) :

        echo "<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='" . plugins_url('/css/meteor-slides-admin.css', __FILE__) . "' />";

    endif;

}
```

This code works fine and hasn't cause any issues, but in debug mode, it does cause this error that I'd like to resolve:

```
// Notice: Undefined index: post_type in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\slides\wp-content\plugins\meteor-slides-1.3\meteor-slides-plugin.php on line 476
```

I haven't been able to fix this error, does anyone have any suggestions, or a different way to add a stylesheet to the admin pages of a certain post type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check for the presence of `'post_type'` as an index of `$_GET` before using it:

```
if ((isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'slide') || (isset($post_type) && $post_type == 'slide')) :
```

Also, you should be using the `wp_enqueue_style` function instead of echoing your stylesheet at `'admin_head'`:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'meteor-slides-admin', plugins_url('/css/meteor-slides-admin.css', __FILE__), array(), '1.0' );
```

[More information on wp_enqueue_style here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style/).

Comment: Thanks so much John, it makes sense that I need to check that before using it, and this totally solved the error that I was getting.

Comment: And thanks for the heads up on wp_enqueue_style, I am using wp_enqueue_script on all my JavaScript, but I was unaware that this existed for stylesheets. It didn't work for me on the first go, but I'll have to read up on it and figure it out.

Comment: I think I know why it didn't work. I thought you were hooking onto `admin_init`; `admin_head` is too late to enqueue a style. I'd suggest hooking onto `'admin_enqueue_scripts'`. It runs before the styles and scripts are printed, and shouldn't change any of the functionality of your code.

Comment: Thanks again John, running wp_enqueue_style on admin_enqueue_scripts worked perfectly. Now I've got all the stylesheets in my plugin properly enqueued!

Answer (score 3):

There are hooks for adding actions to specific pages.. and additionally various variables that hold data about the current page, the post type, the parent file, etc..

`admin_print_styles` would be the correct hook to use for enqueuing styles, and for the edit page your action could look a little something like this..

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-edit.php', 'example_function' ); // Will work for any post type, check inside the callback function
//add_action( 'admin_print_styles-post-new.php', 'example_function' ); // Example
//add_action( 'admin_print_styles-edit-tags.php', 'example_function' ); // Example
function example_function() {
    global $typenow;
    if( 'my_custom_type' == $typenow )
        wp_enqueue_style( 'meteor-slides-admin', plugins_url('/css/meteor-slides-admin.css'), array(), '1.0' );
}
```

In this case the hook is `edit.php`, each admin page has a similar hook. WordPress `admin_header.php` basically has a set of actions that fire, which look like so..

```
do_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', $hook_suffix);
do_action("admin_print_styles-$hook_suffix");
do_action('admin_print_styles');
do_action("admin_print_scripts-$hook_suffix");
do_action('admin_print_scripts');
do_action("admin_head-$hook_suffix");
do_action('admin_head');
```

And `admin.php` sets the hook suffix with the following..

```
$hook_suffix = '';
if ( isset($page_hook) )
    $hook_suffix = $page_hook;
else if ( isset($plugin_page) )
    $hook_suffix = $plugin_page;
else if ( isset($pagenow) )
    $hook_suffix = $pagenow;
```

All the core code aside, the example function i posted further up is a working example you can use for targetting the edit posts(custom type or not) screen....

Hope that helps..

Comment: Thanks for the info t31os, I'll try it out! I tried to use admin_print_styles before, but had trouble getting it to work with custom posts types.